# Can't add ID to parent

Tags: jquery, addclass, attr

```
<div class="search_content_container float_left" style="margin-top:3px;">
            <input tabindex="2" id="simple_search_button" class="search_content_button spaceMar15L" type="button" value="Search" />
        </div>
```

Here is the code that I h ave been trying to work with. No matter what I try, either addClass, or the following, no class or ID is getting added to the parent of the input

```
<script>$("input#simple_search_button").parent().attr('id', 'inputParent');</script>
```

Can I get some help?
Thanks!

Comment: Where is that script located in the html document?

Comment: It's in the head of my html file.

Comment: Horen's answer will solve your problem. http://api.jquery.com/ready | http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to call your script [on document ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) otherwise the script will be executed before your dom elements exist and thus will not be able to select and manipulate them.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("input#simple_search_button").parent().attr('id', 'inputParent');
});
```